# Zoom in on exact location by pinch. Google Maps, Android

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, pinchzoom

All gestures except of Zoom are disabled in my app. I need to Zoom by pinch on the specified location, but keep this location exactly in the center of the screen, no matter where I am trying to pinch. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at `ScaleGestureDetector`.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html  There are methods you can override to do what you are describing.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried ScaleGestureDetector by your advice. It works, but there is a problem. onTouchListener doesn't work with mapView. If I override mapView, write my own onInterceptTouchEvent I lose native functionality of google maps. Even if I try to write my logic and then launch onInterceptTouchEvent of super class - only super class logic works, not mine. Sorry for my English